# Count of pair element in list

Tags: python

```
a = [2,7,9]
b = [[7,9],[1,2],[2,9]]
```

How many pairs in list `[a]` matches pair tuple `[b]`
Notice both pair `[7,9]` and `[2,9]` in list `[a]`. Even though pair `[1,2]` contains a digit of `2`, it doesn't get counted because both digits are not in list `[a]`.
The return value should be 2, the len of the matching pairs.

```
len(filter(lambda l:if_in(b,l),a))
```

Need help creating a if_in function or a simpler way of writing this function all in one. How can I make this function work no matter the size of `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `a` a set and use [set.issuperset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects), checking if `a` is  a `superset` of each sublist:

```
a = [2,7,9]
b = [[7,9],[1,2],[2,9]]


st = set(a)

print(sum(st.issuperset(sub) for sub in b))
2
```

You can go two ways, either making all the sublists sets or as above just make a set, when a is a superset of a sublist then the sublist is a subset of a:

```
In [6]: a = [2,7,9]

In [7]: b = [[7,9],[1,2],[2,9]]

In [8]: st = set(b[0])

In [9]: st.issubset(a)
Out[9]: True
In [10]: st = set(b[1])

In [11]: st.issubset(a)
Out[11]: False

In [13]: st = set(a)

In [13]: st.issuperset(b[0])
Out[13]: True

In [14]: st.issuperset(b[1])
Out[14]: False
```

Obviously as there are only a few numbers in your a list it make more sense to make a set from a and use superset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the subsets of a, you can use itertools.combinations(iterable, r).
Quoting the docs, returns r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [2, 7, 9]
b = [(7, 9), (1, 2), (2, 9)]  
# combinations returns a collection of tuples
# so changed your b items to tuples.

len(filter(lambda x: x in b, combinations(a ,2))
```

Comment: This would take an age for large input and potentially hit a memory error long beofre ever finishing